# Find all unused code in my project (Rider/VSCode)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, rider

#### Goal

Ideally, our projects contain no unused *namespaces / methods / functions* and *classes*.

It is fairly simple to find the number of usages of all of these, for instance;

[image]

Has two usages while the following class is never used:

[image]

Such code can remain unnoticed for quite some time, while providing unwanted overhead to the total solution.
What I'd like to achieve is an overview of all unused code, so developers can easily assess what should and shouldn't stay in the solution.

#### Question

Of course we're not going to manually search for these...
How can we find **all unused code**?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To **find unused code** in Rider:

1. Select *Code | Inspect Code* in the application menu.
2. Choose a scope to inspect (solution, project, or a custom scope).
3. In the *Inspection Results* window, group inspections by issue category (and optionally by issue type).
4. Focus on issues under *Redundancies in code* and *Redundancies in symbol declarations*: [image: Inspeciton Results in Rider]

Alternatively, as you read or edit your code in the editor, you may encounter specific unused code warnings that Rider shows you. If you want to **find all issues similar to one specific issue**:

1. Press *Alt+Enter* to display Rider's code inspection pop-up.
2. Press *Right arrow* to expand options for the current inspection.
3. Press *Right arrow* to expand the *Find similar issues* submenu.
4. Select a scope to find issues.[image]
5. Work with the *Inspection Results* window as shown above.